# SQL show all rows that have certain columns duplicated in a given time period

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table containing the following data: ID, name, barcode, status, time_created

I need to check if the same barcode exists multiple times in a given time period (e.g. one week) and if the last status has changed from 0 to 1.

Question: How can I get the correct results according to given timestamps?

With the following query I can list the duplicated lines:

```
SELECT id, name, barcode, status, time_created 
FROM table_name WHERE barcode
IN (SELECT barcode
FROM table_name
GROUP BY 
barcode HAVING COUNT(*)>1);
```

Results are:

| id | name | barcode | status | time_created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | testname | 123456789 | 1 | 2022-06-22 11:25:17 |
| 36 | testname2 | 123456789 | 1 | 2022-06-22 03:58:35 |
| 37 | testname3 | test | 0 | 2022-06-22 03:57:46 |
| 40 | testname3 | test | 1 | 2022-07-04 10:48:25 |
| 41 | testname | 123456789 | 1 | 2022-07-04 11:19:20 |
| 42 | testname | 123456789 | 0 | 2022-07-02 12:26:39 |
| 43 | testname | 123456789 | 0 | 2022-02-09 03:03:40 |

If I add time interval to the query it still displays results from BEFORE the given interval:

```
SELECT id, name, barcode, status, time_created 
FROM table_name WHERE barcode
IN (SELECT barcode
FROM table_name
    WHERE (time_created BETWEEN '2022-07-02 00:00:00' AND '2022-07-04 23:59:59') 
    GROUP BY 
barcode HAVING COUNT(*)>1);
```

| id | name | barcode | status | time_created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | testname | 123456789 | 1 | 2022-06-22 11:25:17 |
| 40 | testname3 | test | 1 | 2022-07-04 10:48:25 |
| 41 | testname | 123456789 | 1 | 2022-07-04 11:19:20 |
| 42 | testname | 123456789 | 0 | 2022-07-02 12:26:39 |
| 43 | testname | 123456789 | 0 | 2022-02-09 03:03:40 |

Is there an error in my logic or the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to get desired results you need to

1. Get all duplicate `barcode` values ​​in given interval as you do
2. Get previous `status` and row number for each duplicate `barcode` ordered
   by `time_created`. This will give you the ability to get the latest
   values ​​in time and find out the current and previous `status` values.
3. Get the rows with the current `status` equal to 1 and the previous value equal to 0 and the maximum row number

Final query would be like this

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        table_name.*, 
        LAG(table_name.status) OVER (PARTITION BY table_name.barcode ORDER BY time_created) AS prev_status,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY table_name.barcode ORDER BY time_created) AS rn 
    FROM table_name
    JOIN (
        SELECT barcode
        FROM table_name
        WHERE time_created BETWEEN '2022-07-02 00:00:00' AND '2022-07-04 23:59:59' 
        GROUP BY barcode 
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) t ON table_name.barcode = t.barcode
)
SELECT id, name, barcode, status, time_created
FROM cte t
WHERE status = 1 
      AND prev_status = 0 
      AND rn = (
          SELECT MAX(rn) 
          FROM cte 
          WHERE barcode = t.barcode
      )
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=63ea6ccf726b2b6442b9ab9ba9e038a8)